# Odd shaking, when show children element showed

Tags: jquery, html, animation

```js
var $tab = $('a');
var $tabName = $tab.children('.tab_name').hide();
$tab.on('mouseover mouseenter', function(){
    $tabName.stop().show('slide');
});
$tab.on('mouseleave mouseout', function(){
    $tabName.stop().hide('slide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">
    <span class="bracket left">[</span>
    <span class="tab_name">profile</span>
    <span class="bracket right">]</span>
</a>
```

When making simple animation effects it seems like parent element is shaking.
When triggering mouseover `$tabName` shows successfully but when animation is finished the bracket shakes. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Float your spans inside the link to the left. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/luenib/3szy80p5/

```
span {
  float: left;
}
```

You'll need to make some room between the brackets to give more tolerance to the pointer.

Comment: How come floating it removes the shake?